# linux system call getpeername c++

Tags: c++, linux, system-calls

In my c++ application I'm using getpeername system call and it return 0.0.0.0 in the var sa.
there is no error in errno, and the return code is 0.

here is the code:

```
int GetSock(int sock)
{
    struct sockaddr_storage ss;
    socklen_t salen = sizeof(ss);
    struct sockaddr *sa;
    struct addrinfo hints, *paddr, *paddrp;

    sa = (struct sockaddr *)&ss;

    if (getpeername(sock, sa, &salen) != 0) {
        error = errno;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

note: I'm compiling this code with GCC in eclipse.
any help?

thanks!

Comment: Can you show us an example of your code?

Comment: Did you try using getpeername()?

Comment: Looks like it's being used on a socket that isn't connected or that is a server socket.

Comment: Tell us about the socket. What state is it in?

Comment: Check the error messages coming back. you can use the strerror or perror functions to get string outputs. They should give you a good hint why things are going wrong.

Comment: getpeername return 0 ?, if not, what is the value of errno ?, if yes, what is the value of salen ?.

Comment: aix,how can I know in which state the socket is in?

Answer (score 1):

```
        error = errno;
        return -1;
    }
    /* Did you mean to return something right here? */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Upon successful completion, 0 shall be returned. Otherwise, -1 shall be returned and errno set to indicate the error.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getpeername.html)

EDIT: Check what is the value of sock is. getpeername only extracts and stores the peer address of the socket, in this case sock, and stores it in sa. If your socket isn't created or your socket isn't bound to a named socket, what sa points to is unspecified and this may be your case.